# How to edit file json with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9.3

Can I read a attribute from JSON, change, and push back to the JSON.

Exp: I read json file

`let jsonData:NSData = LocalFile.ReadFile(fileName)`

`let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments)`

`if let m_array = json as? [[String: AnyObject]]{...}`

- I change value of m_array
- I want to save the json file with a part new content of m_array ? 
  How can do that?

Comment: I think you can try swiftyJSON. It has a method to convert NSData to JSON object and has a method to get rawString back from JSON object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142091/swiftyjson-object-back-to-string, https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#raw-object